# Sharepoint SPListItem retrieve column index by name

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to retrieve the column index by name for the sharepoint SPListItem? I haven't been able to find a method for doing this.

So for example.

```
SPListItem data;
int32 value = data.getIndexByName("Title");
```

Comment: Doesn't the column index depend on the view?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write extension method

```
public static class SPListItemExtension
{
    public static int getIndexByName(this SPListItem item, string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < item.Fields.Count; i++)
        {
            if (item.Fields[i].InternalName.Equals(name))
            {
                return i;
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

but, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Basically it was to avoid some duplicate code in my libraries. Clearly however it is more effort then I first thought.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the term ID in this context?

Each field will be copied from the entire SiteContentType or the SiteFields to the list itself. By copying the field each field will receive a new ID. You can query a List or the Web by using the FieldID or by using the Internal Name of a field.

```
var field = myList.Fields[SPBuiltInFields.Title];
Console.WriteLine(field.ID);
```

Hope that's what you're lookin for.

Thorsten